# I am trying to unnet an array in other to query the postgres DB

Tags: postgresql

I am call the function but it is returning error that array value must start with "{" or dimension information using

```
    Create or Replace Function get_post_process_info(IN v_esdt_pp character varying[])
Returns setof Record as 
$$
Declare 
post_processes RECORD;
esdt_value character varying;
v_sdsname character varying[];
v_dimension character varying[];
counter int := 1;
Begin
    -- to loop through the array and get the values for the esdt_values
    FOR esdt_value IN select * from unnest(v_esdt_pp)
    LOOP

    -- esdt_values as a key for the multi-dimensional arrays and also as the where clause value
    SELECT distinct on ("SdsName") "SdsName" into  v_sdsname from "Collection_ESDT_SDS_Def" where "ESDT" = esdt_values;
    raise notice'esdt_value: %',esdt_value;

    END LOOP;

  Return ;
End
$$ Language plpgsql;



Select get_post_process_info(array['ab','bc]);
```

Comment: Did you missed a `'` in `Select get_post_process_info(array['ab','bc]);` ?

Answer (score 0):

Your function sanitized:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_post_process_info(v_esdt_pp text[])
  RETURNS SETOF record AS
$func$
DECLARE
   esdt_value text;
   v_sdsname text[];
   v_dimension text[];
   counter int := 1;
BEGIN
   FOR esdt_value IN
      SELECT * FROM unnest(v_esdt_pp) t
   LOOP
      SELECT distinct "SdsName" INTO v_sdsname
      FROM  "Collection_ESDT_SDS_Def"
      WHERE "ESDT" = esdt_value;

      RAISE NOTICE 'esdt_value: %', esdt_value;
   END LOOP;
END
$func$ Language plpgsql;
```

Call:

```
Select get_post_process_info('{ab,bc}'::text[]);
```

`DISTINCT` instead of `DISTINCT ON`, missing table alias, formatting, some cruft, ...
Finally the immediate cause of the error: a missing quote in the call.

The whole shebang can possibly be replaced with a single SQL statement.
But, obviously, your function is incomplete. Nothing is returned yet. Information is missing.

Comment: I have updated the code but am still getting an error

SELECT get_post_process_info( '{ab,cd}':: text[]);
********** Error **********

ERROR: array value must start with "{" or dimension information
SQL state: 22P02
Context: PL/pgSQL function get_post_process_info(text[]) line 15 at SQL statement

Comment: I want to return the function as multidimensional array.
like 
"Select distinct "SdsName" into v_sdsname[counter]...
..." and everything will be assign to post_processes as record. The count will correspond to the index number of the function arguments

Comment: @user3525323: I fixed a typo in my answer. But that's not the cause of the error msg. Maybe `"SdsName"` is not an array type. Can't say more unless your *question* also discloses table definitions. And ideally a test case with sample data and expected result, too.